# find datatypes of children of datasnapshot firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with analyzing datasnapshot that I got from calling `valueEventListener`.
For certain reasons, I opted to use it instead of `childEventListener` when querying the database.

Now, I have this class with the following constructor, where datasnapshot parameter passes the datasnapshot I got from `valueEventListener`:

```
public Trainer(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
    for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        Trainer trainer = snapshot.getValue(Trainer.class);

        name = trainer.name;
        civilNo = trainer.civilNo;
        email = trainer.email;
        age = trainer.age;
        phone = trainer.phone;
        gender = trainer.gender;
        password = trainer.password;
        carNo = trainer.carNo;
        places = trainer.places;
        vehicleType = trainer.vehicleType;
        languages = trainer.languages;
        rate = trainer.rate;
        price = trainer.price;
        contractType = trainer.contractType;
        spokenLanguage = trainer.spokenLanguage;
        trainingAreas=trainer.trainingAreas;
        hourPrice=trainer.hourPrice;
        contractPrice=trainer.contractPrice;
        trainingTime=trainer.trainingTime;
        key = snapshot.getRef().getKey();
    }
}
```

All is well and good when I query for one single trainer, the code works perfectly. The problem is when I try to get a list:

```
public class Trainers {

    private ArrayList<Trainer> trainers;

    public Trainers()
    {
        // Empty default constructor
    }

    public Trainers(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        trainers = new ArrayList<>();

        for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            trainers.add(new Trainer(snapshot));
    }

    public ArrayList<Trainer> getTrainers() {
        return trainers;
    }

    public void setTrainers(ArrayList<Trainer> trainers) {
        this.trainers = trainers;
    }
}
```

An error is generated which tells me that a conversion error occurred:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   worldontheotherside.wordpress.com.drvingapp, PID: 16835
>   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object
>   of type java.lang.L
>       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekh.zzb(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekh.zza(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>       at worldontheotherside.wordpress.com.drvingapp.Classes.Trainer.(Trainer.java:4
>       at worldontheotherside.wordpress.com.drvingapp.Classes.Trainers.(Trainers.java
>       at worldontheotherside.wordpress.com.drvingapp.TrainersActivity$1.onDataChange(Train
>       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeeq.zza(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegl.zzbwe(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegr.run(Unknown Source)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

I traced the problem, and concluded that the problem was because when I passed the datasnapshot to the Trainers class (the class that gets me a list), I took each datasnapshot child that was in the original set I got, and once again passed it to the Trainer class (the class with the single trainer's data).

Here, in turn there is a for loop that gets the children of the datasnapshot passed, which are in this case the actual values for the single trainer (the username, civilNo, etc...), and those cannot be casted to Trainer class.

**What I'm asking for:**

I thought of determining whether the children of the passed datasnapshot are other datasnapshots or the actual values, and then use an if statement based on that in order to do the correct analysis, but I have no idea how to do that. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            trainers.add(snapshot.getValue(Trainer.class);
    }
```

inside your   `public Trainers(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me.

Answer (score 0):

In your Trainer Class instead of doing

```
 for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        Trainer trainer = snapshot.getValue(Trainer.class);
    }
```

you can do something like : (Because you have already fetched the children previously)

```
 for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot)
   {
        Trainer trainer = snapshot.getValue(Trainer.class);
   }
```

Comment: Also depends on your query. What you are querying to firebase. if you are directly accesing childrens in some case and in some cases just outer object.